Use collect to return List<particular type> instead of List<Object>
I want to collect List<TestClone>, but looks like .collect() returns only List<Object>. Is there a way I can get List<TestClone>?
I know .toArray() is there, but want an ArrayList.
public static List<TestClone> getTypes(List<TestClone> args)
{
    return args.stream().map(e -> {
        if (e.schema == null)
        {
            return getAllExportArgs(e);
        }
        else
        {
            return e;
        }
    }).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList<TestClone>::new)); //TODO: ?
}

public static List<TestClone> getAllExportArgs(TestClone args)
{
    //returns List<TestClone>
}


Are you having any errors?

the reason you are having that problem is because the two different paths of your map() operation return two different things.  one returns TestClone and the other returns List<TestClone>.  therefore, the the only common type that the compiler can find between those two types is Object.

git it, thank you.

The issue is with the lambda you call in map - the if branch returns a List<TestClone>, while the else branch returns a TestClone. The intersection between these two types is probably an Object.
Assuming that this is not intentional, one approach is to produce streams in both branches and then flatten them, so you end up with one continuous Steam<TestClone>, that can then be easily collected to a list:
public static List<TestClone> getTypes(List<TestClone> args)
{
    return args.stream().flatMap(e -> {
        if (e.schema == null)
        {
            return getAllExportArgs(e).stream();
        }
        else
        {
            return Stream.of(e);
        }
    }).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList<TestClone>::new)); 
}


Could also be shortened with .flatMap(e -> (e.schema == null) ? getAllExportArgs(e).stream() : Stream.of(e))

@tobias_k true, but I wanted to change as little of the OP's code as possible, so it's easier to spot the difference.

Also true (and what I expected) but maybe add as an alternative below. Also IMHO the description is not entirely correct (or, now that I read again, a bit ambiguous). You do not flatten the list in if but rather create a list (or stream) in else and then flatten both of those. ;-)

@tobias_k, agreed, that wasn't a great description. Edited it in an attempt to make it clearer.

Or in recent versions of Java, use .toList() in place of .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList<TestClone>::new));

Even in Java 8, you can use .collect(Collectors.toList()) instead of .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList<TestClone>::new)) unless you really need to make sure that the result is an ArrayList.
